# Keeping border when updating cell's font in Google Sheet

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am having problems with the border of the cell after sending request to change the font of the cell.

Here is my code:

```
$sheetId = "mySheetId"
$spreadSheetId = "mySpreadSheetId"
$requests = [
               new \Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
                                'repeatCell' => [
                                    'cell' => [
                                        'userEnteredFormat' => [
                                            "horizontalAlignment" => "CENTER",
                                            'textFormat' => [
                                                "foregroundColor" => [
                                                    "red" => 1
                                                ],
                                                "bold"=>true
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ],
                                    'range' => [
                                        'sheetId' => $sheetId,  
                                        'startRowIndex' => 11,
                                        'endRowIndex' => 13,
                                        'startColumnIndex' => 9,
                                        'endColumnIndex' => 10
                                    ],
                                    'fields' => 'userEnteredFormat'
                                ]
                            ])
                        ]; 
$batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest([
                            'requests' => $requests
                        ]);
$response = $serviceGoogleSheet->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadSheetId,
                            $batchUpdateRequest);
```

Here is how it is before the change

[image: before]

After change, the text is changed to what I want but some lines in the border disappeared

[image: after]

Is there a way to keep it as old or I will have to add some update border in my request to change it back ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, I thought that when the the value of `fields` is modified, your issue might be able to be removed. So how about modifying your script as follows?

#### From:

```
'fields' => 'userEnteredFormat'
```

#### To:

```
'fields' => 'userEnteredFormat.horizontalAlignment,userEnteredFormat.textFormat'
```

and

```
'fields' => 'userEnteredFormat(horizontalAlignment,textFormat)'
```

#### Reference:

- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)

Answer (score 0):

### When you specify the property `userEnteredFormat`, it overwrites the previously existing formatting of the cells

Thus, you must specify the border formatting in your request if you wish to preserve it.

Sample:

```php
$sheetId = "mySheetId"
$spreadSheetId = "mySpreadSheetId"
$requests = [
               new \Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
                                'repeatCell' => [
                                    'cell' => [
                                        'userEnteredFormat' => [
                                            "horizontalAlignment" => "CENTER",
                                            'textFormat' => [
                                                "foregroundColor" => [
                                                    "red" => 1
                                                ],
                                                "bold"=>true
                                            ],

                                           "borders" => [
                                             "bottom" => [
                                               "style" => "SOLID"
                                              ],
                                             "left" => [
                                               "style" => "SOLID"
                                              ],
                                             "right" => [
                                               "style" => "SOLID"
                                              ],
                                             "top" => [
                                               "style" => "SOLID"
                                              ]
                                            ]

                                        ]
                                    ],
                                    'range' => [
                                        'sheetId' => $sheetId,  
                                        'startRowIndex' => 11,
                                        'endRowIndex' => 13,
                                        'startColumnIndex' => 9,
                                        'endColumnIndex' => 10
                                    ],
                                    'fields' => 'userEnteredFormat'
                                ]
                            ])
                        ]; 
$batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest([
                            'requests' => $requests
                        ]);
$response = $serviceGoogleSheet->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadSheetId,
                            $batchUpdateRequest);
```